# Meanings of "herald" and 'rupture'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What do **herald** and **rupture** in this paragraph mean?

As you know , the word **rupture**   is used in different fields , from medicine to physics . what I don't understand is  that what this word means in the world of politics . has it got a positive or negative meaning ?
To what reference **rupture** here? That the working people have gained a footing in political sphere?

Does the verb **herald** mean "to praise something or someone loudly or it indicates that Pope was the person that causes this **rupture**.
These have caused me some bewilderment.

> While there are a number of plausible labels that might be attached to the 20th century, in terms of social history it was clearly the age of the working class. For the first time, working people who lacked property became a major and sustained political force. This **rupture** was **heralded** by Pope Leo XIII—leader of the world’s oldest and largest social organization—in his encyclical Rerum Novarum in 1891. The Pope noted that the progress of industry had led to ‘the accumulation of affluence among the few and misery (inopia) among the multitude’; but the period had also been characterized by the ‘greater self-confidence and tighter cohesion’ of the workers. [1] On a global level, trade unions gained a foothold in most big industrial enterprises, and in many other firms too. Working-class parties became major electoral forces—sometimes dominant ones—in Europe and its Australasian offshoots. The October Revolution in Russia provided a model of political organization and social change for China and Vietnam. Nehru’s India set itself the avowed goal of following a ‘socialist pattern of development’, as did the majority of post-colonial states. Many African countries spoke of building ‘working-class parties’ when they could boast no more proletarians than would fill a few classrooms.

Comment: What does a dictionary say?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: I  can search these words in a dictionary . be sure that I have already done it and still can't understand their meaning in this context

Comment: Then state what you found and why you still cannot understand it.  What about the definitions do you not understand?

Comment: OK . I state it immediately

Comment: What parts of the definitions do you not understand???

Comment: I've added the explanation.

Comment: Wrong definition of "herald".

Comment: Can you explain more , please ?

Comment: Where is the quote from? ("Rupture" seems to have been a poor word choice.)

Answer (score 2):

In this sense, the word rupture is meant as the start of change, or change in general in which the working class started to represent themselves politically.

> "**For the first time**, working people ... became a major and sustained political force. This **rupture**..."

Using the context of the text you can see that "For the first time" and "rupture" is used to refer to the same idea or event, which is the working class people moved into politics.

As seen here:

> Rupture:
> Breach or disturb (a harmonious feeling or situation)

*Source: Oxford Dictionary*

Herald, as used here,

> "was **heralded** by Pope Leo XIII"

means a change that is 'led' or 'brought forth by.'

> Herald: Be a sign that (something) is about to happen.

*Source: Oxford Dictionary*

Answer (score 1):

These definitions may help:

> **rupture** *noun*
>
> 2. an end to a friendly relationship or to a peaceful situation

*Source: Macmillan Dictionary*

> **herald** *verb*
>
> to be a sign that something important, and often good, is starting to happen, or to make something publicly known, especially by celebrating or praising it

*Source: Cambridge Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 0):

**Herald** (definition 2):

A person or thing viewed as a sign that something is about to happen.

[(Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/herald)